# User count on daily bases with 30minutes time interval in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to oracle .. I want user count with 30minutes time interval

a user can be logged in more than one time period for ex (start time: 12:30 and end time:12:45) so user will be counted in  2 intervals (12-12:30 and 12:30-1:00) 
I'm taking 12-jul data

**Input**

```
id                   start_date                         end_time
30759224    12-JUL-17 12.02.09.430000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.02.13.310000000 AM
30759224    12-JUL-17 12.02.13.323000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.07.33.343000000 AM
17244836    12-JUL-17 12.06.19.203000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.37.49.890000000 AM
30759224    12-JUL-17 12.07.33.357000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.07.37.813000000 AM
30759224    12-JUL-17 12.07.37.813000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.07.40.690000000 AM
30759224    12-JUL-17 12.07.40.707000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.12.58.470000000 AM
30759224    12-JUL-17 12.12.58.487000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.13.01.937000000 AM
30759224    12-JUL-17 12.13.01.950000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.18.22.193000000 AM
18623011    12-JUL-17 12.13.20.267000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.45.38.013000000 AM
30759224    12-JUL-17 11.46.17.827000000 PM     12-JUL-17 11.51.32.267000000 PM
22118088    12-JUL-17 11.47.03.497000000 PM     13-JUL-17 12.20.17.167000000 AM
```

**Output i needed**

```
    count(id)       interval
   7                1
   2                2
   .                .
   .                .
   .                .   
   2               48
```

There are 48 interval i.e. 24 hours ... 30min interval then 48 interval

```
count(id)       interval
   7                1 (12 - 12:30 am)
   2                2 (12:30 - 1:00 am)
   .                  .
   .                  .
   .                  .
   2               48(11:30 - 12:00 am)
```

I needed only day data....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a numbers table (CTE in this case) and then applying it to :TheDate as a parameter.

```
with Nums (NN) as
(
select level
from dual
connect by level <=48
)
, Periods as
(
select trunc(:TheDate) + (NN-1)/48 as p_start, trunc(:TheDate) + (NN)/48 as p_end, NN as p_id
from Nums
)
select p.*, count(distinct t1.id) as distinct_users
from Periods p
left join Input t1
on t1.start_date < p_end
and t1.end_date >= p_start
group by p.p_id, p.p_start, p.p_end
```

You can swap :TheDate for `sysdate` or a single result subquery if that's what you need

Comment: thankx but 
it's giving me error: not a group by function for this line 
(select p.*, count(distinct t1.id) as distinct_usersend)
....is there any easiest way?

Comment: @steve That's my bad, I forgot to include the group by.

Comment: hey @John, i have checked it again after using trunc oracle is throwing this error(inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER) then i tried to use (TO_TIMESTAMP(:thedate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + (N-1)/48) instead of trunc(sysdate) then i'm getting wrong number of reocords.